# Issue with retinajs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, retina.js

I'm trying to implement [retina.js](http://retinajs.com) plugin but experiencing a weird issue.
When checking my website  with my ipad it seems that the scripts detects that this is a retina screen as it display the @2x logo picture, but instead of displaying the logo with the same size as on a regular screen but with more pixel density, it displays the logo with 2x size. Any idea what the issue is? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your image. The normal image has more padding than retina image. If you can equalize the padding of retina and normal image I think It will be ok.

[image]